# display icons (or content) on mouseover

Tags: jquery

In twitter, when you hover your mouse over a message a star and a reply icon appears on the right.

Similarly, in facebook when you hover your mouse over to an update, the little 'hide' icon appears on the right also giving a little context menu.

I want to have a similar approach in my project for drag & drop handles. What I can decide is the what the most efficient way is it to accomplish this goal.

is it that everytime I hover the mouse onto a div with an id, do I just inject the html with .append() or similar? or do I show/hide the already existing html.. or is there a better way?

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track. Experiment and see what works best for you. Good luck.

Comment: I noticed the same thing happens here.. When I mouse over my mouse on anyones comment, the vote and the flag icon appears on the left :) By the way both of them works but I want to know the correct way

Answer (score 5):

The speediest solution would be to have a hidden  block with the button/drag handle and whenever you mouse-over your element you `.show()` that div and position it accordingly (with css)

`.append()`'ing and removing html code on each mouse-over is certainly possible but will most definitely have some performance hit.

Answer (score 3):

Having done something like this recently, here is an extended example, if you want to test it you will need to grab jquery, jquery ui and my [reset.css](http://simplicityphp.com/export/f6ef828384025e63841354581d779430099e5c5c/source/lib/simplicity/modules/admin/public/css/reset.css).  On hover, the background and border are changed and the previously hidden icons are shown.

```
   <html>
          <head>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

              <style type="text/css">
                  body {
                      font-family: sans-serif;
                      font-size: 13px;
                  }

                  p {
                      font-size: 1em;
                      line-height: 1.5em;
                      margin-bottom: 15px;
                  }                 
                  #items .item .buttons {
                      width: 16px;
                      display: none;
                      float: right;
                      background: transparant;
                  }

                  #items .item .buttons li {
                      height: 16px;
                      width: 16px;
                      margin: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
                      float:right;
                      cursor: pointer;
                  }         

                  #items .item {
                      width: 400px;
                      margin: 10px;
                      border: 1px dotted #fff;
                  }

                  #items .hover {
                      background: #ffe;
                      border: 1px dotted #ccc;
                  }

                  #items .item .contents {
                      margin: 20px 10px 10px 10px;
                  } 
              </style>

              <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
              <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

              <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(function() {
                      $('#items .item').hover(
                          function() {
                              $(this).addClass('hover');
                              $(this).find('.buttons').show();
                          },
                          function() {
                              $(this).removeClass('hover');
                              $(this).find('.buttons').hide();
                          }
                      );

                      $('#items .item .buttons li').hover(
                          function() {
                              $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                          },
                          function() {
                              $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                          }
                      );
                  });
              </script>

              <link
          </head>
          <body>
              <div id="items">
                  <div class="item">
                      <ul class="buttons">
                        <li class="delete ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"/>
                        </li>
                        <li class="config ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-wrench"/>
                        </li>
                        <li class="info ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info"/>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class='contents'>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sit amet arcu ante. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent vel nisl urna, eu ultricies risus.</p> 
                          <p>Nulla eget mauris ac lectus tempor consectetur. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec et lacus ipsum.</p> 
                          <p>Donec rhoncus tincidunt magna, sit amet placerat nulla fringilla iaculis.</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item">
                      <ul class="buttons">
                        <li class="delete ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"/>
                        </li>
                        <li class="config ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-wrench"/>
                        </li>
                        <li class="info ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info"/>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class='contents'>
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sit amet arcu ante. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent vel nisl urna, eu ultricies risus.</p> 
                          <p>Nulla eget mauris ac lectus tempor consectetur. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec et lacus ipsum.</p> 
                          <p>Donec rhoncus tincidunt magna, sit amet placerat nulla fringilla iaculis.</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: thx antz.. Thank you for the example. Actually you described my problem better than me rather then the answer I was expecting :) 
I see that you have the buttons for each of the record you have.. i.e. you have <ul class="buttons"> before each div-contents..  What I was wandedring is whether this <ul class="buttons" exists somewhere on the page floating and whenever I move my mouse over one of the div-contents it is positioned there automatically and set to visible  or I go your way and for each record, I have a seperate div and just show/hide

Comment: Hi Emin,

In this example, I create a separate set of buttons for each item. But you could create one (outside of the items) and absolute position them. Then, your hover function would set the top and left positions using the the offset of the target item. The complicated(ish) bit it to set a variable with the currently hovered item so that the functions attached to the click event of each button know what item to act on. 

In some ways, it is far simpler to do it the first way, and I doubt there would be any major performance hit unless you were displaying many, many items at once.

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way if you want to display nice tooltips - [the tooltip plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/)

You could always append content to the DOM and then remove on hover out, that does work. I think it depends on what you're planning on displaying, if it's images then I'd be tempted to hide them on page load and then show on hover but if it's just a block of text then I'd probably be tempted in appending to the DOM and then removing on hover out.

Another aspect to consider is graceful degradation - would you want some/similar functionality to be available if JavaScript is disabled or none?

If you inspect Facebook with Firefox's [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin, you can see that the ***hide*** div is there when the page is loaded, but is hidden and activated through CSS classes.